# Cabin bag total linear length is 125

Tags: luggage

My cabin bag linear length is 125 cm. Tha bag can use as cabin bag? Please help me to find solution for cabin bag. Thank you.

Comment: Which airline are you flying? You'd have to check the rules for carry-on bags for that particular airline.

Comment: the "linear" size is unfortunately not relevant

Comment: On many (non-US) airlines weight is typically the limiting factor these days

Comment: @Fattie there are quite a few airlines which still use this measure, though often in addition to other limits.

Answer (score 2):

Carry-on (cabin) luggage is almost always restricted in terms of absolute limits on length, width, and height rather than a single linear size. See for example, for Lufthansa:

[image: lufthansa]

Here’s a metric version that compares several airlines:

[image: cabin luggage]

If you’re flying business or first class international, sometimes the cabin attendants will let you store longer items in the coat closet. Economy travelers can sometimes get crutches and canes stored there too.

Otherwise, you’ll likely be asked to gate check your bag if it exceeds the cabin luggage dimensional restrictions (or if the cabin is full).

Comment: Lufthansa these days is also very strict about  carry on weight: 8kg max. That makes the dimensions typically moot: a  regular carry on of 9x16x22 weighs around 5kg empty so you can't fill it. There is not much point in bringing an a even larger bag